# Direct user to thirtd party site from Controller in Asp.NET MVC

Tags: asp.net-mvc

I need to direct user to Paypal site for payment . Is there a way to achieve this from the controller with out the paypal site opening in a new browser?.

Right now I am using Process.Start(url) but would like to find out a better way to d o this preferably with our AJAX and in the same way Return view() behaves.

Thanks in advance.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Does this help?

```
return Redirect("http://paypal.com")
```